# Set a simple delay when closing a window using <a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">X - CLOSE</a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a window that I would like to add a simple delay when they select to close the window. (ie. click the link, takes 2-3 seconds to close) We are wanting this delay because we are playing random "signoff" audio files when they want to close the window, like "Thanks!" or "See you next time!" Currently, without the delay, it plays the first part of the audio and closes. We would like to add the 2 seconds so the complete audio can be heard.

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();" onclick="clicksoundsignoff4.playclip()">X - CLOSE</a>
```

That is the current code for closing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
<a href="" onclick="commenceClosing()">X - CLOSE</a>



function commenceClosing(){
    clicksoundsignoff4.playclip();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.open('','_self').close(); 
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something along these lines if you want to or have to stick with the inline Javascript:

```
<a href="" onclick="clicksoundsignoff4.playclip();setTimeout(function() {return window.close();},2000);">X - CLOSE</a>
```

I'm not sure I'd use an `<a>` tag though as it it's strictly a link (in my opinion).